# how to make seperate Admin folder in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3 and first time using it.I found that I can make controller only in \src\Controller. Here I have put all front end related files. Now I want to make seperate Admin section front end. Please guide how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at prefixed routing:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Create a folder inside `src/Controller` eg `src/Controlelr/Admin/`. Then you can create a controller `src/Controller/Admin/UsersController.php` and the view file `src/Template/Admin/Users/edit.ctp`.